# Create top 10 index fund based on >100 stocks

Tags: python, pandas

## Data

I have a zip with ca M=160 csv files, with one csv file per stock. The ticker symbol is in the file name. Each csv file contain the same columns: *date, txVolume(USD), txCount, marketcap(USD), price(USD), exchangeVolume(USD)*. The date frequency is daily.

Some stocks begin trading in 2014 and some in 2017 so the length of the date column is not equal for all stocks.

## Goal

I want to see how an index fund would develop. The fund's strategy would be to on the first of each month buy the 10 largest stocks (based on market cap). Rebalancing occurs iff there is a "shift" in which stocks are top 10.

I want to use python.

## Initial attempt

I'm familiar with `pandas` `glob` and little bit with `numpy`.

My sketch at solving this is the following

- import all files using the `glob` package
- create a matrices for: **market cap** and **price**. They have *T* rows and *M* columns, where M is the nr of stocks and T is the length of the longest series (circa 4 years).
- Use pandas `.resample('M')` to go from daily to monthly data.
- (ideally the column in the matrix above would have names, therefore using pandas is good since I can set it by `df.columns = list_of_names`)
- create a **returns** matrix based on the price matrix, and a **weigth** matrix based on the market cap matrix.
- return of index = diagonal(Return matrix * Weight matrix transposed)

But I'm a very inexperienced programmer so maybe this approach is stupid. I would like to see if there is a better way of solving the problem I have.

Comment: Add a snapshot of any 2 files and we will be able to help you

Comment: @Aditya https://coinmetrics.io/data/zec.csv and https://coinmetrics.io/data/lsk.csv

Comment: Not sure whether this will help.or not as I don't understand what's an index fund and shifts are..... From your goal you want top 10 shares by market cap right? So what you can do is simply iterate over all your CSV present in a directory(checkout os module) and then sort the table by market cap and save the first entry's file name and it's data, now create a DF with this data and re sort the market cap

Comment: Also importing all your csv's together might be very memory intensive if files are quite big...

Comment: @Aditya the file size is no problem. You can think of it as I have a folder of 1000 stocks for the last 3 years and want to recreate S&P500. However this time it's 10 and not 500